# beginWith() and endWith() functions in PHP

Tags: php, string

How can I write two functions that would take a string and return if it starts with the specified character/string or ends with it?

For example:

```
$str = '|Rajdeep}';

echo beginWith($str, '|'); //Returns true
echo endWith($str, '}'); //Returns true
```

i tried this one

```
function beginWith($haystack, $needle, $case = true) {
if ($case) {
    return (strcmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
}
return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
```

}

```
function endWith($haystack, $needle, $case = true) {
if ($case) {
    return (strcmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
}
return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
}
```

is there any best solution for it

Comment: This is very easy,. Surely you've tried something? Show us.

Comment: There's a very useful function called [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and another called [strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) that might be helpful

Comment: @MarkBaker you mean [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) right?

Comment: @Kypros - StackOverflow's spelling correction is always annoying

Comment: `if (substr($str, 0, 1) == '|') && (substr($str, -1, 1) == '}') { die("You should have read the manpage to start with"); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function beginsWith($string, $char) {
    return $string[0] === $char;
}

function endWith($string, $char) {
    return $string[strlen($string)-1] === $char;
}

$str = '|Rajdeep}';

var_dump(beginsWith($str, '|')); 
var_dump(endWith($str, '}'));
var_dump(beginsWith($str, 'a')); 
var_dump(endWith($str, 'j'));

bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

- [**Demo**](https://eval.in/217970)

Comment: Demos are always a best seller.

Comment: i got what i wanted thanks to john conde

Answer (score 0):

```
function beginWith($myString, $giveChar)
 {
return $giveChar=== "" || strpos($myString, $giveChar) === 0;
 }
 function endWith($myString, $giveChar)
 {
return $giveChar=== "" || substr($myString, -strlen($giveChar)) === $giveChar;
 }
```

Comment: Please give some context to the answers. Code-only answers aren't generally well-reclieved.